# input 4 digit number after typing without pressing enter with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make an input for a four digit number, and exactly when I finish typing the number I want the number to input.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are yo familiar with the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh OP wants to take an input of length four without the user having to press enter.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç how would an MCVE for this problem look like? There's not much you can *try* here without any knowledge.

Comment: Apply duplicate four times.

Comment: What should happen if they enter three digits and then a letter?